# Vim: why doesn't ":normal! i" enter insert mode?

Tags: vim, insert, mode

In `vim`, if I execute the following from the command line

```
:normal! i
```

vim does not enter insert mode.  Likewise the command

```
:normal! A
```

will move the cursor to the end of the line, but the cursor remains in insert mode.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?  Failing that I would like to know an alternative way to enter insert mode from the body of a vimscript function (and have insert mode persist after the function returns of course).

Edit:  Looks like `:startinsert` will fullfill the second part of the question, but I'm still wondering how I can do something like `:normal! A` or `:normal! a` and why those don't simply work as expected.  Simulating "append" with arrow movements is a bad solution, because of things like empty lines and such.

Comment: Take a look at `:help feedkeys()`. It's more flexible than `:normal` but the keys are processed after the script finishes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The normal command considers ending in insert mode as an incomplete command and aborts. From `help normal`:

> {commands} should be a complete command.  If {commands} does not
>   finish a command, the last one will be aborted as if `<Esc>` or `<C-C>`
>   was typed. The display isn't updated while ":normal" is busy. This
>   implies that an insert command must be completed (to start Insert
>   mode, see :startinsert)

`:startinsert` might be the command you are looking for.

`:normal A` can be achieved by appending a bang (`!`) to `startinsert`, as suggested by *Ingo Karkat*. From `help startinsert`:

> When the ! is included it works like "A", append to the line.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw `:startinsert` as well.  But how do I get `:normal! A` or an equivalent from a vimscript function?

Comment: Run your normal commands and end with a startinsert so you end up in insert mode.

Comment: Why does `normal! v` work but not `normal! i`? Why is `v` a complete command but `i` is not?

Comment: @cirosantilli: good question it does seem a bit inconsistent, probably because of convenience, but I'm guessing here.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to already mentioned `startinsert` you can use `feedkeys()`:

```
call feedkeys('A', 'n')
```

will do what you want, but the key you added this way will only be processed after execution of current script/function/mapping/etc is finished.

Comment: It's the only solution to overcome this bug https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4895 and go to insert mode in terminal with vimscript.

Answer (score 12):

Instead  of `:normal A`, use `:startinsert!` (with `!`). It's mentioned in the help.

For `:normal a`, move the cursor to the right, then do `:startinsert`.